# Configuring moin2 to use postgresql as the Wiki Engine

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, moinmoin

I'm trying to setup the Wiki Engine Configuration on the file wikiconfig.py to be able to use postgresql instead of the default filesystem (fs store) but I can't make it work, I've done all the imports (flask_sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy),edited the URI as written in the guide https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/moin-20/latest/moin-20.pdf and changed the name of the database I want to use, the name and the password of the chosen user but every time I start the server and try to log on the platform I get an internal server error. Any ideas on what could cause this problem?

The command I used was:

```
    stores:sqla:postgres://myuser:mypassword@localhost/mywiki_%(nsname)s::%(kind)s
```

The error I get:

```
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  databas "dbname_default" does not exist
```

I even tried to create a new database inside postgresql with the same name of the one in the error log but the problem stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

The problem was the fact that I was trying to create a database in the wrong way: I was using the command line of psql to do all the work, but when I discovered pg_admin everything started to became easier; the only thing that I had to do myself was creating the 3 databases for the wiki (dbname_default, dbname_userprofiles and dbname_users), after that I run the command `./m new-wiki` and everything was ready to go.

Without creating the three databases before running the `./m new-wiki` command the output will be an error so do it before trying to start your wiki